Few questions on the proof that every rank $2$ vector bundle on $\Bbb P^1$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of two line bundles.
I'm looking for some clarification of ideas presented in the following proof for this lemma.

Lemma: Every rank $2$ vector bundle on $\Bbb P^1$ is isomorphic to a direct sum
of two line bundles.
Proof: Tensoring with a line bundle if necessary, it is enough to assume that
$\deg E = 0$ or $-1$. First, by the Riemann-Roch Theorem, we note that $H^0(E) \ne 0$, and so $E$ contains $\mathcal{O}_C$ as a subsheaf. This saturates to a line
subbundle $M\subset E$, and $M \cong \mathcal{O}_C(D)$ for some positive divisor $D\ge 0$. In particular, $\deg M \ge 0$, and denoting by $L = E/M$ we have an exact sequence
$$
0\longrightarrow M \longrightarrow E \longrightarrow L \longrightarrow 0 \tag{1}.
$$
However, $\deg L^{-1}\otimes M = -\deg E + 2\deg M \ge -1$, so that $H^1(L^{-1} \otimes M) = 0$. Since $H^1(\mathcal{Hom}(L,M)) = 0$ implies that every exact sequence of the form $(1)$ splits, we conclude.


Where does the assumption on the degree of $E$ come from? It seems rather ad-hoc to consider only the cases $0$ and $-1$. I now that we can tensor $E$ with any line bundle $\mathcal{O}(k)$ to alter the degree, but even so $0$ and $-1$ seem arbitary.

What does it mean for a subsheaf to saturate to a line bundle?

Why is $M \cong \mathcal{O}_C(D)$ for a positive divisor $D$?

How is $\deg L^{-1}\otimes M = -\deg E + 2\deg M$ concluded? I tried to tensor $(1)$ by $L^{-1}$ and use the additivity of the degree, but this gives $\deg L^{-1}\otimes M = \deg L^{-1}\otimes E - \deg \mathcal{O}_C$.



The saturation of a submodule $N\leq M$ is ${m\in M: \exists r, rm \in N}$. A subsheaf $F\subset E$ of a locally free sheaf $E$ is a subbundle if $F$ and $E/F$ are locally free. E.g. for $A=k[x]$, $xA$ is a line bundle and a subsheaf of $A$ but not a line subbundle

Side comment: Any vector bundle over the projective line splits into line bundles. This is known as the Grothendieck splitting theorem. I don’t recall the proof but I think it’s similar. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%E2%80%93Grothendieck_theorem


It is a usual convention when describing sheaves. A torsion-free sheaf $E$ of rank $r$ over $\mathbb P^n$ is called normalized if $c_1(E)\in\{0,-1,\ldots -r+1\}$. For example, there is a well-known criterion: a rank 2 normalized vector bundle $E$ (or, more generally, reflexive sheaf) over $\mathbb P^n$ is $\mu$-stable if and only if $H^0(E)=0$ (see Okonek, Schneider, Spindler's book Vector Bundles on Complex Projective Spaces, Chapter 2, Lemma 1.2.5). So, the first step of the proof says that a rank 2 vector bundle over $\mathbb P^1$ is always unstable, which is a step in a right direction, because direct sums are always unstable.

A quick search gives this question, where the definition is given. Note that a torsion-free sheaf over a smooth curve is the same thing as a vector bundle over it.

Because for $n<0$ the line bundle $\mathcal O(n)$ over $\mathbb P^1$ has no global sections, that is, no nonzero maps $\mathcal O\to\mathcal O(n)$.

From the exact sequence (1) in the question we get $\deg E=\deg M+\deg L$, and we have $\deg L^{-1}\otimes M=\deg M-\deg L$. From this the statement follows.


